# How to prove by induction that $2^{2^n} + 1$ has $7$ in unit's place?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It must be true,first of all, for $n \geq 2$ . So, firstly I proved that for $n = 2$, it's true. Taking for $n = m$, is true, how can I prove that for $n = m + 1$ ie. $2^{2^{m + 1}} + 1$ has $7$ in its unit place, it is true? Please help.

Comment: The key consequence of $n\geq 2$ is that $2^n$ is a multiple of $4$. You can now use the fact that $2^{4k}=(2^4)^k$ for any positive integer $k$ always ends in $6$.

Answer (score 0):

By Induction hypothesis, $2^{2^m}$ has a 6 in the ones place. Then $2^{2^{m+1}} + 1 = (2^{2^m})^2 + 1$. Note that the first term has a $6^2 \equiv_{10} 6$ in the ones place, adding 1, we get 7 as desired.

Answer (score 0):

**The induction part**:
Taking 
$$2^{2^m} + 1 = ...7$$ true,
$$ 2^{2^{(m + 1)}} + 1 \implies (2^{2m})^2 + 1 \implies (...7 - 1)^2 + 1 \implies .....9 - ....4 + 1 + 1 = .....7$$

Thus it is proved that the number contains $7$ at its unit place.